# Bootstrap button with smaller box with text inside?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to create a bootstrap button for an assignment that has a small white box next to the main text with the smaller box also having text inside. Here is a picture in case my description isn't clear:
[Button example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GVCv.png)

I have looked everywhere and cannot find a way to do this. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Have you tried this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/ ?

Comment: Please check examples under https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/#example

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has this, its called Badges.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  Notifications <span class="badge badge-light">4</span>
</button>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous" /> 


<button class="btn btn-primary">Show Errors <span class="badge bg-white text-dark">4</span></button>
```